# Visual Studio Code new config setting in terminal profiles using Cmder

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, cmder

I am trying to integrate cmder into visual studio code as the default terminal, I used to configure like this in my settings.json.

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
      "/k",
      "C:\\Program Files\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"
  ],
}
```

But now visual code is telling me this configuration is deprecated.

[image]

So, I started to investigate VSC documentation, and it is saying I should import like this:

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
      "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "Cmder": {
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Cmder"
}
```

But it is not working... is starts opening the terminal but closes immediately. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this (leave the rest unchanged):

```json
...
"Cmder": {
      "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\SysWOW64\\cmd.exe",
      "args": ["/k", "C:\\Program Files\\Cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"]
    }
...
```

Alternatively, you can also try with:

- these paths:

  - "C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe"
  - "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
- these args:

  - ["/k", "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"]
  - ["/k", "C:\\Program Files^ (x86)\\Cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"]
  - one of the above in a single string instead of two

Comment: I am trying this solution but it's telling me:

The system cannot find the path specified.

And I already check and my init.bat is in the correct path... 
C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor

so, i'ts very strange..

Comment: still not working :( I tried both.. 

It Still say, The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: I was able to do it like this:
      "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\SysWOW64\\cmd.exe",
      "args": ["/k", "C:\\Program Files\\Cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"]
thanks for the help